# VB.net Cross Process Communication

Tags: vb.net

My target is somehow notify application (Process 1) from another application (Process 2). Would be best if i be able to pass parameters to Process 1.

I googled it and most results was for C# or libraries (witch i don't want).

Comment: 1. How do you start process1, 2. Which language is process1 and 2 written, 3. what and how much of data do u want to pass, 4. Does data flow in both the directions ???

Comment: @inquisitive 1: Pocess 1 - Sartup, Process 2 - User Launched. 2: TITLE says the language - "Vb.net". 3: Just simple string , and some integers. 4: One directional is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named pipes would suffice for this. The idea is to make the startup process a named pipe server. The server always listens at a fixed address which can be taken as a file name. The manually started process then connects to the server and does the communication. The connection and communication part is as simple as writing in a text file.

Ask if you need code, but I recommend you look up the concepts on google. Search for dot Net named pipe server client.